# Order by a field which is a Navigation Property to an Entity - Linq to Entity

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, sql-order-by, navigation-properties

I've got a scenario where I will need to order by on a column which is a navigation property for the Users entity inside my EF model.

The entities:
Users --> Countries 1:n relationship

A simple SQL query would be as follows:

```
SELECT UserId, u.Name, c.Name
FROM users u join countries c on u.CountryId = c.CountryId
ORDER BY c.Name asc;
```

So then I tried to replicate the above SQL query using Linq to Entities as follows - (Lazy Loading is enabled)

```
entities.users.OrderBy(field => field.country.Name).ToList();
```

But this query does not return my countries sorted by their name as the native SQL query above does.

However I continued a bit more and did the following:

```
var enumeratedUsers = entities.users.AsEnumerable();
users = enumeratedUsers.OrderBy(fields => fields.country.Name).ToList();
```

But ordering on the enumeratedUser object for about 50 records took approx. 7seconds

Is there a better way how to omit the Enumerable and without returning an anonymous type?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I just forgot to say that the EF provider is a MySQL one not a MS SQL. In fact I just tried the same query on a replicated database in MS SQL and the query works fine i.e. the country name is ordered correctly, so it looks like I have no other option apart from getting the result set from MySQL and execute the order by from the memory on the enumerable object

Comment: You don't have an anonymous type. var keyword in your case simply hides the IEnumerable<TEntity> type, where TEntity is your Users entity type. The entities.users is an EntityCollection (if I understood your EF model right) already implements the IEnumerable, so you can safely use entities.users.OrderBy(f => f.country.Name).ToList(); However, like Dennis said, you must include all wanted entity associations.

Comment: But that does not return the county names sorted unfortunately

Comment: Try to see if you can get anything from this link. http://thejoyofcode.com/Sorting_associations_in_the_Entity_Framework.aspx

Comment: Thanks Kornelije Petak but that article still orders by in the memory rather on the database

Comment: If he does postData.Comments.OrderBy(c => c.PostedDate), that's sorted in database, at least it should be in MSSQL. Then he attaches these sorted objects to the context. However, I don't know if the Attach() does any element reordering. Otherwise, I don't see how would this be sorted in-memory. But maybe I am wrong. Did you try that?

Comment: How do you check  "this query does not return my countries sorted by their name"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Since I had both columns named Name in both Countries and Users table MySQL Connector was generating this output when order by country.Name was executed:

```
SELECT `Extent1`.`Username`,  `Extent1`.`Name`,  `Extent1`.`Surname`, `Extent1`.`CountryId`
FROM `users` AS `Extent1` INNER JOIN `countries` AS `Extent2` ON `Extent1`.`CountryId` = `Extent2`.`CountryId`
ORDER BY `Name` ASC
```

therefore this will result in ordering on the users.Name rather countries.Name

However MySQL have release version 6.4.3 .NET connector which has resolved a bunch of issues one of them being:

> We are also including some SQL generation improvements related to our entity framework provider. *Source:* http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?3,425992

Thank you for all your input. I tried to be clear as much as possible to help others which might encounter my same issue.

Answer (score 6):

```
var enumeratedUsers = entities.users.AsEnumerable();
users = enumeratedUsers.OrderBy(fields => fields.country.Name).ToList();
```

This is LINQ to Objects not LINQ to Entities.

Above Order By clause will call [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) defined in [Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx)

That is ordering will be done in memory. Hence it will take long time

**Edit**

It looks like a MySQL related issue

You may try something like this.

```
        var users = from user in entities.users
                          join country in entities.Country on user.CountryId equals country.Id
                          orderby country.Name
                          select user;
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do the call directly on the database rather on a .NET object?

Comment: @Ryan yes. Don't use `AsEnumerable`. Just add the `orderBy` and EF will automatically generate the table joins and order by your navigational property

Comment: I just edited my question... doing what you are saying simply doesn't work :(

Comment: tried that already but still no go...I am trying to switch on SQL logging but don't know how to :S

Answer (score 3):

> entities.users.OrderBy(field => field.country.Name).ToList();
>
> But this query does not return my countries sorted by their name as the native
>   SQL query above does.

**Yes, it does not return `Countries` but only `Users` sorted by the name of country.**
When this query is executed, the following sql is sent to DB.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u join countries c on u.CountryId = c.CountryId
ORDER BY c.Name asc;
```

As you can see, the result does not include any fields of `countries`. As you mentioned the lazy loading, `countires` are loaded through it when needed. At this time, `countries` are ordered as the order you call it through the lazy loading. You can access `countries` through the Local property of a entity set.

This point tells you that if you want `user` sorted by the name of `country` and also `countires` sorted by the name, you need the eagerly loading as @Dennis mentioned like:

```
entities.users.Include["country"].OrderBy(field => field.country.Name).ToList();
```

This is converted to the following sql.

```
SELECT u.*, c.*
FROM users u join countries c on u.CountryId = c.CountryId
ORDER BY c.Name asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Include`?

```
entities.users.Include["country"].OrderBy(field => field.country.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: I have lazyloading enabled on the object context...that means I can omit the Include, right?

Comment: Just tested it now...in fact it returns the same result set as without the Include (country Name not sorted)